# How to extract only if it not extracted already?

Tags: makefile, gzip, tar

I have a makefile which has an action to extract an archive. It does it even when the archive has already been extracted (and there were no changes to it).

```
all:
     tar zxvf soplex-1.7.2.tgz
```

Is there a way to prevent this? I tried using the **k** flag to make it keep the existing files but it gives me this

```
soplex-1.7.2/src/vector.cpp
tar: soplex-1.7.2/src/vector.cpp: Cannot open: File exists
```

Comment: In general, you cannot do something with Make if you do not know how to do it *without* Make. What if you use the `--keep-newer-files` option?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly good make practice but this sort of operation doesn't really fit into the way make does things either (unless you want to use a known sentinel file from inside the tarball as your marker).

```
all:
        tar -df soplex-1.7.2.tgz 2>/dev/null || tar -xvf soplex-1.7.2.tgz
```

(You can manually supply the `z` flag to `tar` if your `tar` can't figure out that it needs it itself.)

Also note that this is *very* expensive in the case that one of the later files in the tarball is the one that is missing/modified since it requires two sequential scans of the entire tarball and the related disk activity.